How would the shape of a circle be different if we change it this way?
What if we define a circle not as the set of points with the distance $R$ from the center, but rather as a set of points which have at least one geodesic path to the center of the length $R$?
Will the circles become much more complicated? Will the circles on toruses become everywhere dense after some radius?
Are there online visualizations of cirles defined this way on toruses and cones?

On a sphere, since geodesics are great circles, the  circles you  are saying are still standard circles. In any case,  for given center  $x_0$ and radius $r$,  it’s a compact  (the image  of   the  circle of $T_{x_0}M$  via the  exponential map)

If by torus you mean the flat torus, then the radius $r$ circles you mention would just be the projection of a normal radius $r$ circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to the torus $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{T}^2$. So indeed they tend to be everywhere dense, in the sense that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is some radius $R$ such that any circle of radius $\geq R$ is at distance $<\varepsilon$ of all points in the torus. Something like $R=10/\varepsilon^2$ should work

@SaúlRM yes I meant everywhere dense as a limit with infinite radius...

In fact it looks like these circles should be everywhere dense in almost any compact manifold (the spheres would be an exception), if I get a nice result I will post it as an answer

@SaúlRM awaiting! Also, my motivation was to study similar spaces but with the opposite property - the greater radius, the less is the density. I believe, such spaces are negative-dimensional.
